# Powershell: REGEXP to modify paths to different *nix styles

Tags: regex, powershell, cygwin

I'm using Rsync and ICACLS to sync two (windows) directories and to do so, I must the same path translated to several 'styles': cygwin *nix, remote *nix, UNC. (see examples below)

I'm using the following code to do so, and while it works, the regexp I'm using could be surely made more robust and better working (as you can see, I'm doing a replace of a replace, wich i find ugly at best...)

```
$remote="remotesrv"
$path="g:\tools\example\"
$local_dos=$path
$remote_dos="\\$remote\"+(($local_dos -replace "^\w","$&$") -replace "(:\\)|(\\)","\")
$local_nix="/cygdrive/"+($local_dos -replace "(:\\)|(\\)","/")
$remote_nix="//$remote/"+(($local_dos -replace "^\w","$&$") -replace "(:\\)|(\\)","/")
"Local DOS  : $local_dos"
"Remote DOS : $remote_dos"
"Local *nix : $local_nix"
"Remote *nix: $remote_nix"
```

the output is:

```
Local DOS  : g:\tools\example\
Remote DOS : \\remotesrv\g$\tools\example\
Local *nix : /cygdrive/g/tools/example/
Remote *nix: //remotesrv/g$/tools/example/
```

Can someone please help me with the regexes above? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
$local_dos  =  $path
$remote_dos = "\\$remote\$path" -replace ':', '$'
$local_nix  = "/cygdrive/$path" -replace ':?\\', '/'
$remote_nix = "//$remote/$path" -replace ':?\\', '/'
```

The dos ones are pretty simple and aren't really using regex much.

For the nix ones, `:?\\` means "\ optionally preceded by :".  We're replacing that with a forward slash.

This should work fine for the vast majority of non-pathological cases.  However, it's not bulletproof.  Crazy file names with slashes or colons in them could easily break this.

Comment: Thanks, it works beautifullty, and it's much more understable than what I had conceived.. :)

Answer (score 0):

The usual approach is to split a path into its component parts, translate the parts, then recombine the parts for the destination OS. For Windows/Cygwin/DOS, the component parts are:

- Drive
- Path
- Filename (the part before the first '.' in most filesystems)
- File extension(s) (where `zim.tar.gz` would have filename = `zim` and extension = `.tar.gz`)

Long-term, this is easier and faster than trying to do it all at once. (I know -- I've tried it all-at-once before.)

Perl's [File::Spec](http://search.cpan.org/dist/File-Spec/) modules may be worth a look for ideas if you can read Perl code.

Comment: Hi,and thanks for the quick reply. While I agree on the approach, I must use Powershell. I'm a newbie on the regex matter, so could you please elaborate on the split & recombine suggestion? I do undestand regex group (match1)|(match2) but i'm not into it enough to conveive a working solution

Comment: Sorry that I was unclear -- I meant to look at the Perl code to get ideas, then implement what you need in Powershell.